# Как защититься от DDOS атаки?

Tags: php, apache, безопасность, взлом, ddos

Лог апача забит вот этим:

```
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:05.995596 2019] [:error] [pid 19621:tid 47703230371584] [client 159.192.96.176:30324] File does not exist: /var/www/html/up.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:06.496367 2019] [:error] [pid 19619:tid 47703224067840] [client 159.192.96.176:30598] File does not exist: /var/www/html/test123.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:07.016980 2019] [:error] [pid 19623:tid 47703228270336] [client 159.192.96.176:30867] File does not exist: /var/www/html/test123.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:07.536110 2019] [:error] [pid 19622:tid 47703238776576] [client 159.192.96.176:31149] File does not exist: /var/www/html/fb.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:08.037741 2019] [:error] [pid 19620:tid 47703224067840] [client 159.192.96.176:31403] File does not exist: /var/www/html/paylog.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:08.557560 2019] [:error] [pid 19621:tid 47703234574080] [client 159.192.96.176:31681] File does not exist: /var/www/html/paylog.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:09.076222 2019] [:error] [pid 19619:tid 47703226169088] [client 159.192.96.176:31966] File does not exist: /var/www/html/x.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:09.600198 2019] [:error] [pid 19623:tid 47703232472832] [client 159.192.96.176:32215] File does not exist: /var/www/html/cnm.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:10.141288 2019] [:error] [pid 19622:tid 47703232472832] [client 159.192.96.176:32494] File does not exist: /var/www/html/test404.php
[Thu Jul 25 22:56:10.661308 2019] [:error] [pid 19620:tid 47703228270336] [client 159.192.96.176:32709] File does not exist: /var/www/html/test.php
```

И видимо воркер апача уходит в рестарт:

```
[Wed Jul 10 07:05:58.152792 2019] [:error] [pid 3210:tid 47122401523456] [client 129.28.148.105:24681] File does not exist: /var/www/html/knal.php
[Wed Jul 10 07:06:05.025446 2019] [:error] [pid 3209:tid 47122285246208] [client 129.28.148.105:25085] File does not exist: /var/www/html/cmd.php
[Wed Jul 10 07:06:18.132386 2019] [:error] [pid 3208:tid 47122378409728] [client 129.28.148.105:25443] File does not exist: /var/www/html/shell.php
[Wed Jul 10 07:08:04.499676 2019] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 14195:tid 47122069013888] AH00297: SIGUSR1 received.  Doing graceful restart
[Wed Jul 10 07:08:04.620884 2019] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 14195:tid 47122069013888] AH00292: Apache/2.4.39 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2s mod_bwlimited/1.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 10 07:08:04.620921 2019] [core:notice] [pid 14195:tid 47122069013888] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
[Wed Jul 10 07:09:50.290744
```

Я верно понимаию что это DDOS ? Ip Товарища который долбиться в несуществующие скрипты постоянно меняется

Что делать? Куда бежать? В техподдержку хостинга? Менять апач на nginx? Делать какие-то конфигурации? Или все труба, осталось только работу менять?))

PHP 7.1.30
Server version: Apache/2.4.39
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)

Comment: Во-первых, 2 (два) запроса в секунду — это не просто не DDoS,  это вообще можно считать почти полным отсутствием нагрузки. Во-вторых, никакой DDoS не сможет отправить сигнал SIGUSR1 — кто-то на вашем сервере специально запустил перезагрузку апача, вот и выясняйте кто

Comment: И вообще в 6-7 часов утра обычно работает logrotate, в план работы которого входит перезагрузка воркеров апача. Если я угадал, то эта перезагрузка абсолютно нормальна, и вам не нужно предпринимать совершенно никаких действий

Comment: Наши восточные братья в просторах сети попросту ищут незакрытые дыры для порабощения сервера и мира в дальнейшем.